# How to use In Operator in Sforce.Connection.query in Javascript?

Tags: soql, javascript

I am using it like this inside scripts in VF page:

```
var queryResult = sforce.connection.query("Select Name,Id From product2 where Id in \'" + myArray+"\'");
```

But I am getting malformed query error. Any idea where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this worked.

I did like this.Its working fine :

```
var queryResult = sforce.connection.query('Select Name,Id from product2 where Id in (\'' + myArray.join('\',\'') + '\')' );
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you **can't concat** a variable array.  In addition query has not option to pass a parameter.

Having said that, I think that you should convert that variable using a `for` and `Join`.

Try this:

```
for(var i in myArray){ myArray[i] = 'id='+ myArray[i]}
var query = "Select Name,Id From product2 where " + myArray.join(' or ') , 
queryResult = sforce.connection.query(query);
```