# How to use IN operator in VF page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to get contacts from an array of account ID's from VF page.

```
SELECT Id, AccountId, Name, Email, Key_Contact__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN (\'' + accountIds.join('\',\'') + '\')
```

I tried using => [This will help for less number of records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28357/how-to-use-in-operator-in-sforce-connection-query-in-javascript)

When i have 7k records I am hitting a malformed query exception due the salesforce 100000 limit.
Please help if there is any work around for this

Comment: I think you can just `SELECT Id, AccountId, Name, Email, Key_Contact__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds`, why you need to use dynamic SOQL?

Comment: Binding a variable is only possible in apex code

Comment: How can you use SOQL in VF otherwise?

Comment: API calls using the AJAX Toolkit.https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_connecting.htm

Comment: I would say that processing 7k records directly on VF is not the best idea and would recommend moving this logic to Apex. And even though I would suggest doing some aggregation beforehand with "rollup" fields or something like that

Comment: otherwise, you might hit some limits, what is your use case for processing so many records on SFDX, have you considered pagination or limiting?

Comment: I am working on complete different scenario where we can't do pagination. So I am doing some calculation to divide array of ID  which will limit record and process  API call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117576/discussion-between-nbr-and-ytiq).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want, you can use a function like this (breaks up array into equal pieces):

```
const breakUp = (arr,n) => Array.from(Array(n)).map((_, index) => arr.slice((arr.length/n) * index, (arr.length/n) * (index + 1)))

let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
console.log(breakUp(arr, 3))
```

To break your recordIds in multiple arrays and then do a few API requests